# TS file not getting called

Tags: angular

I am trying to insert the selector in to my html using angular 2.

I have created html and ts file as below along with appmodule.ts.

My html page seems to be not calling the ts file (weather.component.ts) on its load. its not displaying the template defined in typescript file. i have tried using system.import in html head tag but with no luck.

Appreciate your inputs.

**HTML**

```
<div>
    <h3>Weather for {{weather.city}}</h3>

</div>
```

**weather.component.ts file**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
selector: 'weather',
template: '<h1>u are here </h1>'

})

export class WeatherComponent {
public weather: Weather;

constructor() {
this.weather = { temp: "12", summary: "Barmy", city: "London" };
}
}

interface Weather {
temp: string;
summary: string;
city: string;
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import {ROUTER_PROVIDERS} from 'angular2/router';
import { UniversalModule } from 'angular-universal';
import { WeatherComponent } from './components/weather.component';

@NgModule({
bootstrap: [WeatherComponent],
declarations: [WeatherComponent],
imports: [UniversalModule],
})

export class AppModule {
}

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Answer (score 0):

Because it doesn't work like that.

When you give your component a selector (here `weather`), you are supposed to use it as a tag in your html.

This would give, for your HTML :

```
<div>
    <h1>You are here</h1>
    <weather></weather>
</div>
```

And in your template HTML :

```
<h3>Weather for {{weather.city}}</h3>
```

Comment: thanks. i have now updated the html and ts file (there is no template html as said above). still no luck, please let know.

<div>
    <h1>You are here</h1>
    <weather></weather>

</div>

ts -------

@Component({
    selector: 'weather',
    template: '{{weather.city}}'
        
})

Comment: From your post, you have both a HTML file and a template in your component. But anyway, did it work for you ?

Comment: yes i have one html file ts file respectively. ts file is having a template. 

weather is a selector defined in ts file, i need to display value of weather.city in html file.

Comment: Then follow my answer.

Comment: tried, can you check the html and template posted in first comment, are they fine ?

Comment: my angular application works fine when i execute using npm start in command prompt, which invokes a lite server and loads the page correctly, however when i load the html using IISexpress, it doesn't work as expected.

please let know how to run angular application through IIS